# Q about torus automorphism example

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, automorphism-group, tropical-geometry, toric-varieties

I am working through the book ["introduction to tropical algebra"](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~janos/COURSES/238900-13/Tropical/MaclaganSturmfels.pdf) and page 70 and 71 example 2.2.10 states

"An automorphism of the torus is an invertible map specified by
Laurent monomials. Thus the automorphism group of $\mathbb{T}^n$
isomorphic to GL(n, Z). Here the matrix entries are the exponents of the
monomials.

The invertible integer map $U =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$
represents the
automorphism $(x, y) \mapsto (xy, x^{−1}y^{−2})$ of the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ and of its coordinate
ring $\mathbb{C}[x^{±1}, y^{±1}]$. The image of the curve $X = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{T}^2
: f(x, y) = 0\}$ in Example 1.8.1 under the automorphism U is the curve defined by
$(U ◦ f)(x, y) = c_2 + c_5x + c_1y + c_3xy + c_4x^2y^2$ "

Where example 1.8.1 states

"Let X be the curve in $(\mathbb{C}^∗)^2$ defined by the polynomial $f(x, y) = c_1 + c_2xy + c_3x^2y+c_4x^3y + c_5x^3y^2$
Here $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5$ are any complex numbers..."

My question is, how is the curve in example 2.2.10 obtained from the given automorphism? For example after applying the given automorphism why does $c_1$ gain a $y$ factor and why is the $c_2$ term $c_2 xy$ not mapped to $c_2 (xy)(x^{−1}y^{−2})=c_2y^{-1}$ ?

I think there must be something I am missing here, so any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it indeed contains some inaccuracy.

Normally, when we apply a transformation $U$ to a subset $X=\{(x,y):f(x,y)=0\}$, then we have to apply $U^{-1}$ on the defining equation because
$$(a,b)\in U(X)\ \iff\ U^{-1}(a,b)\in X\ \iff\ f\left(U^{-1}(a,b)\right)=0\,.$$

The notation $U\circ f$ especially with the stated strict equality is not too clean.

What the received equation instead describes, is thus the $U^{-1}$ transform $U^{-1}(X)$ of the curve $X$, but of course, the $U$ transform can be obtained the same way.

So, $(x,y)\in U^{-1}(X)\iff f(U(x,y))=0\iff$
$$\matrix{c_1+c_2y^{-1}+c_3x+c_4x^2y+c_5xy^{-1}=0& \iff & |\,\cdot y\\
  c_1y+c_2+c_3xy+c_4x^2y^2+c_5x=0\,.}$$

Comment: Great, thank you for the comprehensive answer